# VBA Error 91 after correct execution with for each loop and cell comments

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code that works fine until the end of the MsgBox:

```
Sub CommentsAsFootnotes(myTemplate As Variant, ByRef footnotespage1 As String, ByRef footnotespage2 As String)
Dim rngTemp As Range
Dim rngComment As Range
Dim footnote As String
Dim i As Integer

    On Error Resume Next
    Set rngComment = myTemplate.Sheets("Seite 1 ").Range("B14:T35").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeComments)
    On Error GoTo 0
    i = 1
    'If rngComment is Nothing
        'Exit Sub
    'End If
    For Each rngTemp In rngComment
        rngTemp.value = rngTemp.value & CStr(i)
        rngTemp.Characters(Start:=Len(rngTemp.value), Length:=1).Font.Superscript = True
         MsgBox rngTemp.Comment.Text
        ' error thrown here
    Next rngTemp

    footnotespage1 = footnote

End Sub
```

The message box is shown with the correct content. 
However, when I click "OK", an error is thrown "Error 91, Object variable or with block variable not set" and the debugger highlights the line with the message box.

Do you have any idea what could cause this error?

Comment: Its works for me, is there any other content you can add around this that might help?

Comment: In response to Shai's correct workaround for this answer: The reason for that is based on "merged cells". If you have a comment on a merged cell, using "SpecialCells(xlCellTypeComments)" will give you a range that contains all cells that are included in this merged cell, but only one of them actually includes a comment. So it is in general a good idea to doublebeck the range as suggested by Shai.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because that current range doesn't have a comment inside, add an `IF` when the cell doesn't have any comment inside, like this :

```
If rngTemp.Comment Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "No Comment found !"
Else
    MsgBox rngTemp.Comment.Text
End If
```

Comment: But the OP said the code got into the loop and past the `MsgBox`. I think this is something to do one of the cells in `rngComment` (which is populated by the selection of all commented cells) have some form of special property. Its almost like it was deleted after `rngComment` was made.

Comment: @ShaiRado, I don't think that is correct since the OP's looping through `rngComment` range which is previously set with `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeComments)` method so that it either is `Nothing` (and thus it would stop the code upon entering the  `For Each...`  loop) or is a valid `Range` object  collecting cells with comment actually there!

Comment: Nope, actually, above solution solved it. The debugger probably stopped within the next iteration. Why that is - I have no idea, because I have used specialcells...

Comment: I have no idea how that worked! but well done @ShaIRado for spotting a fix. I could even re-create the break.

Comment: @derMAx, I wouldn't say why. BTW are you missing any `i = i + 1` statement and update notes marker?

Comment: Jep, I saw the missing i+1 statement as well, thank you all ;)

Comment: I found the root of the error, see my comment in my question - imo, Shai's solution is the correct workaround