# VBA loop through comments with specialcells - multiple iterations

Tags: vba, excel

Referring to my previous question: 
[Loop through comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38824069/vba-error-91-after-correct-execution-with-for-each-loop-and-cell-comments/38824226#38824226)

When I loop through the comments using specialcells, some iterations happen multiple times. I.e. for the code below, some cells that contain a comment (`rngTemp.Value`) are modified up to three times (i.e. the number is added three times to the cell value):

```
On Error Resume Next
    Set rngComment = myTemplate.Sheets("Seite 1").Range("B14:T35").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeComments)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If rngComment Is Nothing Then
        'Do nothing
    Else
        i = 1
        For Each rngTemp In rngComment
            If rngTemp.Comment Is Nothing Then
                'do nothing change the if then else
            Else
                MsgBox rngTemp.value
                rngTemp.value = rngTemp.value & CStr(i)
                rngTemp.Characters(Start:=Len(rngTemp.value), Length:=1).Font.Superscript = True
                footnote = footnote & CStr(i) & ". " & rngTemp.Comment.Text & "; "
                i = i + 1
            End If
        Next

        footnotespage1 = footnote
    End If
```

Do you know that error and know how to fix or work around it?

Comment: It's a weird behavior that, like the one of your previous post, I couldn't replicate. So put a break after `Set rngComment `, step through your code and once you get there query in the Immediate Window (Ctrl-G) for `?rngComment.Address` and see if it fits your expectations. Then keep it checked during every iteration of the `For Each rngTemp `loop

Comment: Did it. It literally iterates through the same sheet two times, without leaving the for-loop.... Something in my sheet must be seriously messed up there.

Comment: maybe `CommentsAsFootnotes` is being called multiple times: check your modules for every call of it. You may want to post the whole code and let us help you

Comment: Actually, stepping through the code finally made it. I always underestimate the power of the debugger. My code should perform the same operation on several pages, but did not update the "rngComment" object, so it iterated through the code several times.

Comment: Which also casts new light on your previous question. I'd suggest you to review it after introducing necessary "rngComment" updating and let other users who'll read it know if ".SpecialCells(xlCellTypeComments)" method actually works (i.e no need for any subsequent "If rngTemp.Comment Is Nothing") or not.

Comment: :) found it. Best reason ever. Read my comment in the other question.

Answer (score 0):

Change the code to the below:-

```
If rngTemp.Comment Is Nothing Then
    'do nothing change the if then else
Else
    If rngTemp.Characters(Start:=Len(rngTemp.value), Length:=1).Font.Superscript <> True Then 
        MsgBox rngTemp.value
        rngTemp.value = rngTemp.value & CStr(i)
        rngTemp.Characters(Start:=Len(rngTemp.value), Length:=1).Font.Superscript = True
        footnote = footnote & CStr(i) & ". " & rngTemp.Comment.Text & "; "
        i = i + 1
    End If
End If
```

If it ends in a superscript already then won't do it at all.